# How to implement a delayed release for a reset button?

Tags: delay, reset, dpdt

I have a microprocessor with two lines, /RESET and /HALT, which are independently pulled to +5V DC.  To reset the processor, both of these lines must be grounded for at least 100 ms -- they may not be wired together and treated as one line.  How do I create a circuit such that, when a single DPDT reset button (debounced) is pressed, both of these independent lines are grounded, and when it is released, they stay grounded for at least 100 ms?

Comment: How is this different from your previous question? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/322127/how-to-create-a-100ms-delay-between-button-pressed-and-line-grounded

Comment: (1) And why do you need a delay? (2) Why are you using a double-throw button? (3) How are the inputs debounced if they halt the micro?

Answer (score 1):

This kind of problems are usually addressed by a specialty circuit called "voltage monitor", or "voltage supervisor". Check distributors for ICs like MIC803, APX809, MAX809, etc.

These are 3-pin devices, and no need for any de-bouncing.

Answer (score 0):

Build a pair of these mosfet circuit for 2 of the pins, connect both mosfet gate together. Time delay depends on C1 and R3.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGGkaf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The basic idea could work, but I think you want NMOS not PMOS. Also, the specific part you chose is really not suitable. A small signal MOSFET such as the BSS138 is more than adequate. Note that the OP said it is a 5V system, so you may want to change VCC to 5V.